# Reliable way to programmatically determine the CLR Version for a particular Visual Studio Build

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, clr

Historically I had been relying on the Registry Key Name ***CLR Version*** under ***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\\CLR Version*** to determine the mapping between the CLR, .NET Framework Version build and the Visual Studio Version. As you can see from the below screen shots, the CLR Version was reliably present for the prior versions and I believe even for versions prior to the once mentioned below
[image]

But when I checked the same registry key for Visual Studio 11.0 - 2012, this information is missing.
[image]

So, my question is, what is the reliable way to determine the CLR Version for a particular Visual Studio Build?

PS:

- I would like to determine the CLR Version programatically from a Native C++ Program so that would mean ***Environment::Version*** is not available.
- This method should work across VS Versions Reliably
- I cannot rely on any existing assembly and use ICLRMetaHost::GetVersionFromFile and deprecated GetFileVersion

Comment: I have deleted my answer since after your update its not "to your question".

Comment: Using undocumented registry keys is a really bad idea.  This makes *very* little sense in general.  If you don't know what assembly you are going to load then you cannot possibly pick the right CLR version.

Comment: @HansPassant: The functionality is part of a wrapper over a VS Build Environment which is part of a large automation supposed to work across a wide VS Versions past and future across multiple target systems which are not in control. When invoking, through configuration and switches, we can determine the VS Version and thereby map to the assembly type, CLR and CRT version. Unfortunately, though the mapping is definite, using a predefined hard-coded matrix may loose the flexibility and maintainability and determining it dynamically from the host system is desirable.

Comment: @Abhijit why don't you hard code CLR version as `4.0.30319` for VS 2012 as a special case?

Comment: Is it an option to start devenv.exe process and then use clrver.exe to obtain the CLR version? You can read more about clrver.exe at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff427522.aspx